# Handle big data with MySQL and Redis

Tags: php, mysql, apache, redis, centos

I need help from database gurus.

I have a big database with more than 1.5 gb when exported as SQL file in MySQL.

Problem I'm facing is now that the query on tables like stats that hold millions of data just crashes the server.

I'm now thinking of few solutions to this and I'm leaning towards Redis implementation for large tables only then have both Redis and MySQL work together. I think I should keep MySQL as it has a lot of complex relations set up especially when defining permissions and access control lists. Also I'm not sure Redis is safe for storing sensitive data like payments.

Is this the best way to solve the issue?

Altenative to this I hear is MySQL sharding which I heard is quite effective for performance gains.

What would you do in this case?

**UPDATE - This is what I have from MySQLTuner:**

```
-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 9d 1h 9m 33s (98M q [126.517 qps], 2M conn, TX: 354B, RX: 15B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 82% / 18%
[--] Total buffers: 232.0M global + 2.8M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 647.2M (10% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (876/98M)
[!!] Highest connection usage: 100%  (152/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/294.2M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (148B cached / 2M reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 81.0% (64M cached / 79M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 36845
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (27 temp sorts / 7M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 8358004
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 44% (8M on disk / 18M total)
[!!] Thread cache is disabled
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (400 open / 266K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 38% (398/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (42M immediate / 42M locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 67.8M/128.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Set thread_cache_size to 4 as a starting value
    Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
Variables to adjust:
    max_connections (> 151)
    wait_timeout (< 28800)
    interactive_timeout (< 28800)
    query_cache_size (> 64M)
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    thread_cache_size (start at 4)
    table_cache (> 400)
```

Comment: 1.5GB is nothing for MySQL, are you sure you configured your MySQL properly? It seems you haven't touched it and you're already thinking different software would help :)

Comment: 1.5 GB is nothing by modern standard. Any modern MySQL flavor should be able to handle this volume with no issue.

Comment: I suppose query optimisations would help. The problem arises when I do a query for reports that go through stats table with millions of rows and it also does a few left joins as they are required. Should I try not do joins at all as it slows down significantly?

Comment: As others have said, 1.5gb is trivial for MySQL to handle if properly structured. I'd suggest creating a new question tagged mysql with your specific query that 'crashes the server'.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information. What database engine are you using? What's the actual query? What does the `EXPLAIN` say? What are your configuration variables? What's the hardware (CPU, RAM, HDD) that you're running thins thing on? All these are **vital** before telling you anything that'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a universal limit, but 1.5GB shouldn't even be considered as Big Data. You didn't provide the number of TPS (Transactions Per Second), which may be indicative of your workload.

However, switching to non-relational solutions causes much more problems than trying to optimize your RDBMS. So, you should ask yourself:

- Which queries crush the server?
- Do your queries use good indexes?
- Do your long-running queries lock tables?
- Is your server well configured? Did you set innodb_buffer_pool_size to use 80% of avaible memory?
  Take a look at these slides from Percona: http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/WEBINAR2012-03-Optimizing-MySQL-Configuration.pdf
- Are you using things which make the system slower? For example, SELinux is bad wherever you need good performance.

If all the answers are "yes", then consider using other solutions:

- Upgrading the hardware (in this order of importance: more RAM, faster disks, more CPUs with fast BUS)
- MySQL partitioning
- XtraDB Cluster, from Percona
- The Shard Query storage engine, which makes some sharding and load balancing

Answer (score 0):

1.5 Gig of data is not big data, MySql can handle it with no problem if configured correctly.

So before you look at anything else then your MySql db make sure you already tried and ruled out everything from this list:

- you have adjusted your mysql config (defaults sucks)
- you are using indexes
- you optimised your queries (make sure you actually use indexes)
- you use as much ram as you can affort

At the end of this list you will know lots more about MySql and probably you wont need to add extra components to your stack. ( Or you can hire a DBA and get the same outcome )